# How to change values in dictionary by another dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json:

```
{ 'a': ['c','d','e'],  
  'b': ['a','c','e'],  
  'c': ['a','b','d'],
....and so on
```

And also I have dictionary:

```
{'a':'abc','b':'cdf'}
```

Now, I want to change all these 'a' to 'abc' in the json file:

so, finally my json looks like:

```
{ 'abc': ['c','d','e'],   
  'cdf': ['abc','c','e'],  
  'c': ['a','cdf','d'],
....and so on
```

Comment: if you have nested elements then you may need recursion to replace values in list and replace dictionary with new name.

Comment: if you don't have nested dictionares then you could load it as `pandas.DataFrame` and use something like `df.replace({'a':'abc','b':'cdf'})`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ dic.get(key, key): [dic.get(i, i) for i in value] for key, value in js.items() }
```

Where `js` is a dictionary representing your json and `dic` represents your dictionary `{'a':'abc','b':'cdf'}`

Comment: It will not work if both dict are not in same length.

Comment: Welcome. I just add my answer too. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {'a' : ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    'b' : ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    'c' : ['a', 'b', 'd']}

B = {'a' : 'abc', 'b' : 'bcd'}

C = {}

for key in A.keys():
    
    #Checking for key new value
    if key in B.keys():
        new_key = B[key]
    else:
        #If there is no new value for key
        new_key = key
        
    C[new_key] = []
    
    for element in A[key]:
        #Checking for new value of element
        if element in B.keys():
            new_element = B[element]
        else:
            #If there is no new value for element
            new_element = element
        
        C[new_key].append(new_element)
```

C is the modified version of A

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this:**

```py
dict_1 = {
    'a': ['c','d','e'],
    'b': ['a','c','e'],
    'c': ['a','b','d']
}

dict_2 = {'a':'abc','b':'cdf'}

for key in list(dict_1):
    if key in dict_2:
        dict_1[dict_2[key]] = dict_1.pop(key)

print(dict_1)
```

**Output:**

```
{'c': ['a', 'b', 'd'], 'abc': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'cdf': ['a', 'c', 'e']}
```